# What is I8(Integer of unspecified type) in arm NEON data types?

Tags: assembly, neon

Integer in NEON data types

| type | 8-bit | 16-bit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Unsigned integer | U8 | U16 |
| Signed integer | S8 | S16 |
| Integer of unspecified type | I8 | I16 |

What's difference between `I8` and `S8` ?

Comment: Presumably applies to operations like shuffles, or binary addition / subtraction, where the operation would be the same for signed or unsigned.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: One example of such a difference are saturated operations.  The location you saturate at differs between signed and unsigned bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments have already described them, Peter Cordes has summarized the idea perfectly:

> Presumably applies to operations like shuffles, or binary addition /
> subtraction, where the operation would be the same for signed or
> unsigned

---

Focusing the answer on Neon's instruction set, most of the instructions only accept a specific data type, the rules are:

- When `I` is valid, also `S` and `U` are
- When only data size is specified, `U`, `S` and `I` are valid (also P and F)
- Some instructions ignore the datatype
- When there is not a datatype, any one is valid

---

It is fairly easy to know which instructions will specify a datatype, i.e.:

- In orther to get the absolute value, `VABS`only accept `S` types (note that it also allows F32).
- There are instructions which accept `I`, hence they also accept `S` and `U`, such as bitwise AND (`VAND`).

Comment: Answers should generally be self-contained.  If that means repeating what comments have explained, then do so.  Feel free to copy the text of my comment if you want.